# How to run Devenv.exe from other exe program?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, batch-file, devenv

I am trying to create an application(.exe) that will be used for building projects in different configuration by using Visual studio's **Devenv.exe**. I have try create a batch file to do this as bellow :

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE"
devenv "%PROJECT_PATH%\MySolution.sln" /Rebuild "Release" /project "MyProject"   /out "%PROJECT_PATH%\AutoBuildErrorLog.txt"
```

where **PROJECT_PATH** is the directory where **MySolution.sln** is kept.

And **MyProject** is a project under **MySolution** solution

Above batch file is running fine and giving expected result. i.e., MyProject is building successfully.

Now I am trying to run above command through an exe application. I have try calling command as bellow :

```
const char devncmd[] = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe";
const char slncmd[] = "\"C:/Solution Folder with spaces in folder name/MySolution.sln\"";
const char rebuildCmd[] = "/Rebuild";
const char releasecfg[] = "Release";
const char projectcmd[] = "/project";
const char projectnamecmd[] = "MyProject";
const char outcmd[] = "/out";
const char outName[] = "\"C:/Solution Folder with spaces in folder name/AutoBuildErrorLog.txt\"";

int rc = _spawnlp(_P_WAIT, devncmd, slncmd, 
     rebuildCmd, releasecfg,
     projectcmd, projectnamecmd,
    outcmd, outName, NULL);
```

On running above code, I got bellow error message.
[image: Error message from DevEnv.exe]

Above message convince me that DevEnv.exe is able to execute.

Next, I try change solution path name (slncmd[]) as bellow:

```
const char slncmd[] = "C:/Solution Folder with spaces in folder name/MySolution.sln";
```

Devenv run without any error but in my out file **AutoBuildErrorLog.txt** it suggest there is a problem with build path.

```
The following files were specified on the command line:

Folder
Name/MySolution.sln

These files could not be found and will not be loaded.
```

Can anyone please point out what might went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the folder containing `devenv.exe` you'll note there is also `devenv.com`.

When automating Visual Studio for builds, use `devenv.com`. Batch files will automatically use the `.com` rather than `.exe` (because of the `PATHEXT` variable) and you'll notice your batch file does not specify the extension.

PS. Rather than hardcoding the path to `devenv` – it can be changed while installing – use the `VS120COMNTOOLS` environment variable to construct the path (in a batch file:`%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\ide\devenv`).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. i try change from .exe to .com. Still got same result. This time nothing write into my AutoBuildErrorLog.txt.

Answer (score 0):

check command line is able to run first, then try to do automatic in C code.

```
devenv project.sln /Clean

devenv project.sln /Rebuild Debug /Out "Test.log"
```

Comment: This all works fine for me except when I try to run it with an installer vdproj file :( then it just says the command was ran incorrectly but I got a version running in powershell so there is an issue with how it needs to be written in the cmd prompt. Very frustrating. This finally worked in cmd running from the project root folder that had a sub installer project verbatim `devenv "solution.sln" /Build "Debug" /Project "Installer\Installer.vdproj"`